# SpecFlow - ordering of multiple BeforeScenario methods

Tags: testing, specflow

I'm getting my feet wet with SpecFlow, and I do really enjoy it.

Except for a few thorny issues... like feature and scenario setup code.

In one "general-purpose" file called `InfrastructureSteps.cs`, I have general setup code that should be run for every scenario - so my method looks something like this:

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void SetupDbContext()
{
    // define some basic stuff, set up a database transaction context etc.
}
```

This needs to be run before **every** scenario, and so far, it has worked just fine.

But now, I have two scenarios in a test-specific steps file that also need quite extensive setup before they can be run. So I marked their scenario in the `.feature` with a tag:

```
@needs_extra_setup
Scenario: .....
   Given .....
   When .....
   Then ......
```

and implemented a test-specific `BeforeScenario` setup method:

```
[BeforeScenario("needs_extra_setup")]
public void DoExtraSetupForMyScenario()
{
   // do stuff
}
```

It works - it gets called - but it gets called **before** the general-purpose `[BeforeScenario]` method gets called :-( and thus it fails - stuff being setup in that general-purpose setup method isn't present and causes my code to fail.

So is there any way in SpecFlow to order the `[BeforeScenario]` methods? Or can I tell a specific `[BeforeScenario]` method to first execute a "base" `[BeforeScenario]` method like calling a base method in a overriden method?

Of course I could call that "base" `[BeforeScenario]` method explicitly - but that seems a bit like a sledge-hammer approach.....

Any ideas? Thoughts? Pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can (and probably shouldn't) order the execution order of your scenarios.

But you could use some other [hooks](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks) such as BeforeFeature and maybe get around it that way.

Another way is to simply have a flag that check if the general stuff has been set in the specific stuff, calling into the SetupDbContext method (or preferably the thing that SetupDbContext calls in turn).

Use the [ScenarioContext.Current](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext) dictionary to store your flags.

I hope you found this helpful

Comment: You can also use FeatureContext.Current for use with BeforeFeature

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I ended up using

```
if(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("needs_extra_setup"))
```

at the end of the [BeforeScenario] method.
It is described on the page already linked to by Marcus: [SpecFlow Hooks](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks)

Comment: Thanks for this! Was looking for a way to discriminate between Web (i.e. Selenium) and non-web acceptance tests, that Hooks documentation gave me exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible in v2 of specflow, which is in beta at the time of writing.

The step binding attributes have an optional order property which allows you to specify the order of the hooks. Smaller numbers will be processed first and the default order value is 10,000.

Comment: Thanks! - `[Order]` did make it into the [final release](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/)